# Excel VBA Object Invoked has Disconnected from its Clients

Tags: excel, vba, excel-2016

So I'm working on a user form to pull data from different excel sheets and build a summary sheet based on user inputs. All of this is within one workbook without external links, and most of the solutions I have seen for this error are the result of trying to connect/open an outside source. The code works until it reaches the tenth entry, then it gives me the Object Invoked has Disconnected from its Clients error and restarts excel. I have tried commenting out the tenth entry and the same error occurs at another interval.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()


If TextBox_1.Value > 0 Then

   Worksheets("FirstSheet").UsedRange.Offset(3).Resize(Worksheets("FirstSheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3).Copy
   Worksheets("Template").Rows("4").Insert shift:=xlDown

End If

If TextBox_2.Value > 0 Then

   Worksheets("SecondSheet").UsedRange.Offset(3).Resize(Worksheets("SecondSheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3).Copy
   Worksheets("Template").Rows("4").Insert shift:=xlDown

End If

If TextBox_3.Value > 0 Then

   Worksheets("ThirdSheet").UsedRange.Offset(3).Resize(Worksheets("ThirdSheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3).Copy
   Worksheets("Template").Rows("4").Insert shift:=xlDown

End If

...

If TextBox_9.Value > 0 Then

   Worksheets("NinthSheet").UsedRange.Offset(3).Resize(Worksheets("NinthSheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3).Copy
   Worksheets("Template").Rows("4").Insert shift:=xlDown

End If

**If TextBox_10.Value > 0 Then
   Worksheets("TenthSheet").UsedRange.Offset(3).Resize(Worksheets("TenthSheet").UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3).Copy
   Worksheets("Template").Rows("4").Insert shift:=xlDown
End if**
```

Is the issue stemming from the number of repetitions within the code? Is there a specific item within the worksheet itself that I should be looking for that would be causing this issue?

Comment: I tried to bold the "If TextBox_10" statement, but it doesn't look like it worked. Sorry.

Comment: How many sheets are you copying and what is the row count and column count on the largest ?. I can't replicate your error with 20 sheets each one 1000 rows by 100 columns = 13Mb spreadsheet. What windows version, excel version and how much memory do you have ?

Comment: No more than 20 sheets, None with more than 100 rows. Excel 2016, Windows 10. I was able to get it working, so I'll be posting an answer shortly. Thanks for trying to help.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to specify each sheet separately, you can use a loop like this

```
Option Explicit
Private Sub Submit_Click()

    Dim wb As Workbook, wsSource As Worksheet, wsTarget As Worksheet
    Set wb = ThisWorkbook
    Set wsTarget = wb.Sheets("Template")

    Dim sheetnames As Variant
    sheetnames = Array("", "FirstSheet", "SecondSheet", "ThirdSheet", "ForthSheet", _
    "FifthSheet", "SixthSheet", "SeventhSheet", "EighthSheet", "NinthSheet", "TenthSheet")

    Dim n As Integer, sName As String, sValue As String
    Dim rngSource As Range, rngTarget As Range

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    For n = 1 To UBound(sheetnames)
        sName = "TextBox_" & CStr(n)
        sValue = Me.Controls(sName)
        If Len(sValue) > 0 Then

            ' define ranges
            Set wsSource = wb.Sheets(sheetnames(n))
            Set rngSource = wsSource.UsedRange.Offset(3).Resize(wsSource.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3)
            Set rngTarget = wsTarget.Rows(4)

            ' copy to Template
            rngSource.Copy
            rngTarget.Insert shift:=xlDown
            Application.CutCopyMode = False

        End If
    Next
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    MsgBox "Finished", vbInformation
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

So I was able to get it running last night by splitting the code up and using variables to execute the commands. Not sure why it worked, but it worked.

```
Private Sub Submit_Click()

Dim Template As Range
Dim FirstSheet As Range

Set Template = Worksheets(2).Range("$A$4")
Set FirstSheet = Worksheets(3).UsedRange.Offset(3).Resize(Worksheets(3).UsedRange.Rows.Count - 3)

If TextBox_1.Value > 0 Then

   FirstSheet.Copy
   Template.Insert shift:=xlDown

End If
```